# sql: generate additional dates depending on the period

Tags: sql

Got data like this:

| date_start | date_end | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.04.2022 | 20.04.2022 | 1 |
| 21.04.2022 | 11.05.2022 | 7 |
| 12.05.2022 | 15.07.2022 | 5 |

And i need get separete dates between start\end month, like this:

| date_start | date_end | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.04.2022 | 20.04.2022 | 1 |
| 21.04.2022 | 30.04.2022 | 7 |
| 01.05.2022 | 11.05.2022 | 7 |
| 12.05.2022 | 31.05.2022 | 5 |
| 01.06.2022 | 30.06.2022 | 5 |
| 01.07.2022 | 15.07.2022 | 5 |

any ideas?

Comment: So what are your rules for generating the rows?  It seems like you want to add rows based on the date_start and date_end of the existing rows, but it is not clear exactly what the requirements are.  You are going to have to explain the requirements if you expect to get an answer.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like a row for each month contained within the period where the begin/end bound of the full month is truncated to the period intersection. This can be easily solved with a table that contains all potential begin/end month dates to which you can inner join. What RDBMS are you using and what is the data type of these date columns?

Comment: the rules are simple, if the beginning of a period and the end of a period have different months, I need to split into as many rows as the difference in months. So that in each row in for the period, the end date and the start date would be with the same month. I am using oracle 11.2g base.
As I see it, the solution here should be through connect by with changing dates through add_months, but now I have not found a solution

Comment: In general, I would like to solve this in pure sql, without creating additional tables and other things.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, everything works correctly on different arrays of dates, but it seems to me that there may be a much simpler and more concise solution for this case?

code below:

```
select d_surcharge_period_from,
       d_surcharge_period_to,
       case
         when column_value = 1 then
          d_surcharge_period_from
         when column_value > 1 then
          trunc(add_months(d_surcharge_period_from, column_value - 1), 'mm')
       end as period_beg,
       case
         when lead(column_value) over(order by d_surcharge_period_from, column_value) = 1 then
          d_surcharge_period_to
         else
          last_day(add_months(d_surcharge_period_from, column_value - 1))
       end period_end,
       n_rate_value,
       column_value
  from (select to_date('01.04.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as d_surcharge_period_from,
               to_date('20.04.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as d_surcharge_period_to,
               1 n_rate_value,
               0 as n_used
          from dual
        union all
        select to_date('21.04.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as d_surcharge_period_from,
               to_date('11.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as d_surcharge_period_to,
               7 n_rate_value,
               0 as n_used
          from dual
        union all
        select to_date('12.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as d_surcharge_period_from,
               to_date('15.07.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as d_surcharge_period_to,
               5 n_rate_value,
               0 as n_used
          from dual),
       table(cast(multiset (select level
                     from dual
                   connect by add_months(trunc(d_surcharge_period_from, 'MM'), level - 1) <= d_surcharge_period_to) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 order by d_surcharge_period_from,
          column_value
```